# Representation of Actor that is primary and secondary

Tags: uml

how can we represent an actor that his type primary and secondary in the same time.
example an actor who will launch the application and he will attend for a result how can i  REPRESENT that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between a primary actor and the secondary actor is that the first one has a goal with the use case and the second one is needed to accomplish that, but the second actor does not have a goal within the use case. Therefor are those definitions mutually exclusive and can a primary actor never be a secondary actor. A primary actor is capable to execute actions within the use case.

The same user can have different roles. Those different roles can be primary and secondary actor for a certain use case. Therefor can the same user be a primary and secondary actor in one use case. But that does not imply that one actor can be primary and secondary actor at the same time.